# how to use first parameter in history.pushstate

Tags: javascript, html5-history

After reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history and playing around with history.api I am wondering how to use first parameter in

```
history.pushState(stateObj, title, url);
```

I understand that stateObj is a js object so something like this:

```
{
  par1 : 'par1',
  par2 : 2
}
```

But how I have to use it? What method gives me the possibility to retrieve this object later.

I also understood that title is not used right now and I have to use my own javascript methods  to change the title of the page. Am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is extremely easy: all you have to do is:

```
history.pushState({
  par1 : 'par1',
  par2 : 2
}, '', 'url');
```

To get this object you have to do

```
var tmp = history.state;
```

tmp will be equal to

```
{
    par1 : 'par1',
    par2 : 2
}
```

Regarding the second question. As far as I know - you are right. For example you can send your title in that object, you were asking in the first question.